# Truncated created file to 500 bytes in android

Tags: android, xml, android-xml

I'm trying to create a KML file using XmlSerializer, but when I open the file this is truncated to 500 bytes only.

I don't understand why?

my code:

```
public void onCreatXML() {

        KML kml = new KML();

        try {
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = Xml.newSerializer();
            writer = new StringWriter();
            xmlSerializer.setOutput(writer);
            //Start document
            xmlSerializer.startDocument("UTF-8", true);
            //Open tag
            xmlSerializer.startTag("", KML.KML);
            xmlSerializer.startTag("", KML.DOCUMENT);
           ----
            onWrite(writer.toString());

        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void onWrite (String writer) {
            FileOutputStream fic;
            String loc;
            String zaza = "ROCKWELL COLLINS";

            try{

                context.deleteFile("Test.kml");
                fic = context.openFileOutput("Test.kml", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                OutputStreamWriter wfic = new OutputStreamWriter(fic);

                wfic.write(writer);
                wfic.close();

            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, i forget to close the doc before write it.
I just add a xmlSerializer.endDocument after closing tags, and it works

Thanks to all